# Foreach Loop in PowerShell Not in Order

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am working with a config file for PowerShell and every time I call a foreach loop to grab the data it grabs it in the wrong order. See below:

config.ini

```
[queries]

query01=stuff1

query02=stuff2

query03=stuff3

query04=stuff4
```

The `foreach` loop:

```
#Loads an INI file data into a variable
$iniContent = Get-IniContent 'config.ini'
#grabs the hashtable for the data under the [queries] section
$queries = $iniContent['queries']

foreach($query in $queries.GetEnumerator())
{
    write-host $query.name
}
```

I get the following output:

```
stuff1
stuff4
stuff2
stuff3
```

I am assuming this has something to do with asynchronous processing from PowerShell, but what would be the best way to handle the queries from the `config.ini` file in the order I store them in there?

Note: I added the number to the end of the query (`query01`) just for testing purposes. The queries will not have them in my final `config.ini`.

EDIT:

`Get-IniContent` function:

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePath
    {
        “^\[(.+)\]” # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        “(.+?)\s*=(.*)” # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change both hashtable declarations to ordered dictionaries. If you only change

```
$ini = @{}
```

to

```
$ini = [ordered]@{}
```

your $ini is now an ordered dictionay but the nested hashtable created at

```
$ini[$section] = @{}
```

is still an unordered hashtable. You would need to change both of them to ordered dictionaries.

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
  $ini = [ordered]@{}
  switch -regex -file $FilePath
  {
    “^\[(.+)\]” # Section
    {
        $section = $matches[1]
        $ini[$section] = [ordered]@{}
        $CommentCount = 0
    }
    “(.+?)\s*=(.*)” # Key
    {
        $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
    }
  }
  return $ini
}
```

**EDIT**

There is also a [ConvertTo-OrderedDictionary script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ConvertTo-OrderedDictionary-cf2404ba) on the Script Center that allows you to convert hashtables and arrays to ordered dictionaries if you don't want to rewrite your function.

Comment: This was perfect. I was missing the other `$ini[$section]` in my function. Everything works perfect now.

Comment: Great catch @StephenP !

Answer (score 4):

I assume your call to `Get-IniContent` is [this script from the Microsoft Script Center](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ea40c1ef-c856-434b-b8fb-ebd7a76e8d91)?

It returns a `[hashtable]` and in PowerShell `[hashtable]`s are not ordered.

You could try changing this line in the `Get-IniContent` function:

```
$ini = @{}
```

To this:

```
$ini = [ordered]@{}
```

This may allow the items to be kept in order.

Comment: I tried to use `[ordered]` or in my case `$ini = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`, but the order was still messed up. I think you might be on to something though in my `Get-IniContent` function.